# Employee privacy when using company iPhone on own Wi-Fi

Tags: privacy, wifi, mobile, iphone

If I use a company iPhone on my own home Wi-Fi, does the employer still have visibility on activity? If so, how much assuming there are no hidden keylogging programs.

Comment: If they had possession of the phone before giving it to you, you can assume anything could be installed. If anything could be installed, they can know all your activity. There is no easy way to know if there is a key-logging app running (if its not listed, of course).

Answer (score 3):

If the device is enrolled on your company's network (using a device enrollment / Mobile Device Management process), they could have a lot of visibility.  iOS allows for a "*always-on VPN*" ([link](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/)).  This allows for either certain or all applications to use a particular VPN connection; which could be your place of employment.  With the implementation of enforced / transparent proxies and custom CA's, he/she can also intercept SSL data easily and see what you do on the network.

So in essence, your employer could see a lot of traffic going back and forward to your device, manage your apps, remove all/some of your content, etc.